# get select option value using $(document).ready function in jQuery from multiple dynamic record?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my code

```
foreach($test as $val){

<select name="change" id="change-<?=$val['id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $val['id'];?>">
     <option value="">Select Value</option>
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
     <option value="3">three</option>                
 </select>
}
```

I want every different record blank value alert in every 3 min. so please help me. thanks!

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var change = $('#change').val();
    if (change == '') {
       alert('Please Select Shipping Destination!');
    }

});
```

Comment: Where is your jquery effort? UPDATE: EDIT your answer, don't paste in comment..

Comment: Hi. So you have multiple dropdown elements and you want to check each dropdown selected value is blank or not?? And if there is any selected element found blank, it should alert.. is that what you want to implement??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the interval you can use plain JavaScript's [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method.

In order to find and iterate over all your `select` fields, you can use jQuery's "[starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector and [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    setInterval(function() {
        $("select[id^='change-']").each(function(i) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == '') {
                alert('Please Select Shipping Destination!');
            }
        });
    }, 3 * 60 * 1000);

});
```

Note that this will create an alert for **every** `select` that is empty. Probably not very user friendly.